# Alternative for the DF Player (mp3 playback module)?

Tags: mp3

The DF Player and all it's clones are super cheap on Aliexpress and similar websites, one can be bought under $1.5. The problem is that the low power state of the module is non existing with around 30mA drawn is that state. That makes the module unsuitable for battery usage. Powering the module down using an external MOSFET does work, however the setup time of the module is about 1.5 sec to 3 which is too much.

I am looking for something that could provide high quality playback of mp3 files, possibly more primitive than the DF Player but could go low power & wake up into playback in under 0.5 sec. Cost should also remain about the same. Can be an IC as well as long as I can actually buy it from somewhere.

Comment: See [Don't ask](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) regarding specific product recommendations.

Comment: I don't see the conflict? I have provided an explanation of the problem with the module and am looking for a module or IC that has the same basic functionality but uses low current during sleep mode & wakes up more quickly.

Comment: This is a shopping question and off-topic for this site. VTC.

Comment: @Sparky256 So how or where (or both) this information can be discussed? I even got a good reply for it. I can see how this seems like a shopping question but it's mainly because there are a number of modules called by this name and that IC they use is the same one. This is similar to asking about a Hex inverter IC from various processes. Is this really a shopping question?

Answer (score 1):

You must be not the only one being concerned about this issue; good designers and manufacturers usually listen to their customers and improve their products accordingly.

I think device you refer to is based on YX5200 chip, which has rated current of 20 mA. There's newer device, [YX5300](https://github.com/simulatedsimian/yx5300/blob/master/docs/YX5300-24SS%20Datasheet%20V1.0.pdf), having rated current of 10 mA and standby current of less than 200 uA (as declared in the datasheet). I think this is the device you need.

However I am concerned about the responsibility of the manufacturer - datasheet does not state its name and contact details; it does not state source of the intellectual property used. Most probably someone is missing their royalties, and buying this device you are participating in counterfeit - e.g. they glued several ready-to-use SoC parts together, and used freely available C source code, which most probably has requirement in its license for the source code origin declaration in the documentation for the end product.

Comment: The problem with the new model is that it's not easy to obtain. I understand your concern and yes... probably a reason for no obvious contact details. 4D Systems, which is a well known company makes a module called SOMO-II which is the same thing you see on eBay for $1.5. The IC PN is shaved off in the photo inside the datasheet. However I think it's the same so perhaps the source is fine?

Comment: The only way to see if source is fine is contact source and check with it. Not doing it is just a roulette. If your product assumes users (not for your personal use) you will risk your reputation (at least). I know another producer, called VLSI from Finland, but their chips are $20 for one, and about $7 for the amount.